# Serialize model fields related through another model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have four models linked like so:

```
class A:
  some fields

class B:
  ForeignKey('A')

class C:
  ForeignKey('B')

class D:
  ForeignKey('C')
```

Now, when I serialize D, I want to also serialize related model fields from A. Of course, this can be done using nested serializers like so:

```
class ASerializer:

  class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = ('id', some fields)

class BSerializer:
  a_s = ASerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = B
    fields('id', 'a_s')

class CSerializer:
  b_s = BSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = C
    fields('id', 'b_s')

class DSerializer:
  c_s = CSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = D
    fields('id', 'c_s')
```

However, I want to only display the fields of related A objects when serializing D and not include C or B objects. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can define `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` in `class CSerializer`:

```
class DSerializer:
  c_s = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  @staticmethod
  def get_c_s(item):
     return item.c.b.a

  class Meta:
    model = D
    fields('id', 'c_s')
```

Document: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Comment: why make it a static method?

Comment: Its only a habit of mine. You can remove it if you want. If remove it, you need change to `def get_b_s(self, item):`.

Comment: Sorry I had to re-edit the question. The depth was 1 more. How would I do it in this case?

Comment: It doesn't work. AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: can you post all field data in `item.c.b`? If in pycharm, use evaluate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185047/discussion-between-ngoc-pham-and-rahul-sarma).